# Multiple different errors in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm working on this project in Scheme and these errors on these three particular methods have me very stuck.

Method #1:

```
; Returns the roots of the quadratic formula, given
; ax^2+bx+c=0. Return only real roots. The list will
; have 0, 1, or 2 roots. The list of roots should be
; sorted in ascending order.
; a is guaranteed to be non-zero.
; Use the quadratic formula to solve this.
; (quadratic 1.0 0.0 0.0) --> (0.0)
; (quadratic 1.0 3.0 -4.0) --> (-4.0 1.0)
(define (quadratic a b c)
  (if
  (REAL? (sqrt(- (* b b) (* (* 4 a) c))))
  ((let ((X (/ (+ (* b -1) (sqrt(- (* b b) (* (* 4 a) c)))) (* 2 a)))
        (Y (/ (- (* b -1) (sqrt(- (* b b) (* (* 4 a) c)))) (* 2 a))))
     (cond
        ((< X Y) (CONS X (CONS Y '())))
        ((> X Y) (CONS Y (CONS X '())))
        ((= X Y) (CONS X '()))

   )))#f)

Error: 
assertion-violation: attempt to call a non-procedure [tail-call]
                     ('(0.0) '())
1>
assertion-violation: attempt to call a non-procedure [tail-call]
                     ('(-4.0 1.0) '())
```

I'm not sure what it is trying to call. (0.0) and (-4.0 1.0) is my expected output so I don't know what it is trying to do.

Method #2:

```
;Returns the list of atoms that appear anywhere in the list,
;including sublists
; (flatten '(1 2 3) --> (1 2 3)
; (flatten '(a (b c) ((d e) f))) --> (a b c d e f)
(define (flatten lst)
        (cond
          ((NULL? lst) '())
          ((LIST? lst) (APPEND (CAR lst) (flatten(CDR lst))))
          (ELSE (APPEND lst (flatten(CDR lst))))
        )
)
Error: assertion-violation: argument of wrong type [car]
                     (car 3)
3>
assertion-violation: argument of wrong type [car]
                     (car 'a)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, when I'm checking if it is a list before I append anything.

Method #3

```
; Returns the value that results from:
; item1 OP item2 OP .... itemN, evaluated from left to right:
; ((item1 OP item2) OP item3) OP ...
; You may assume the list is a flat list that has at least one element
; OP - the operation to be performed
; (accumulate '(1 2 3 4) (lambda (x y) (+ x y))) --> 10
; (accumulate '(1 2 3 4) (lambda (x y) (* x y))) --> 24
; (accumulate '(1) (lambda (x y) (+ x y))) --> 1
(define (accumulate lst OP)
    (define f (eval OP (interaction-environment)))
    (cond
        ((NULL? lst) '())
        ((NULL? (CDR lst)) (CAR lst))
        (ELSE (accumulate(CONS (f (CAR lst) (CADR lst)) (CDDR lst)) OP))
    )
)

Error:
syntax-violation: invalid expression [expand]
                  #{procedure 8664}
5>
syntax-violation: invalid expression [expand]
                  #{procedure 8668}
6>
syntax-violation: invalid expression [expand]
                  #{procedure 8672}
7>
syntax-violation: invalid expression [expand]
                  #{procedure 1325 (expt in scheme-level-1)}
```

This one I have no idea what this means, what is expand?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. code has `(let () ...)` which clearly evaluates to `list?` so the extra parentheses seems odd. `((let () +) 1 2) ; ==> 3` works because the `let` evaluates to a procedure, but if you try `((cons 1 '()) 1 2)` you should get an error saying something like `application: (1) is not a procedure` since `(1)` isn't a procedure. Also know that case insensitivity is deprecated so `CONS` and `REAL?` are not future proof.
2. `append` concatenates lists. They have to be lists. In the `else` you know since `lst` is not `list?` that `lst` cannot be an argument of `append`. `cons` might be what you are looking for. Since lists are abstraction magic in Scheme I urge you to get comfortable with pairs. When I read `(1 2 3)` I see `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))` or perhaps `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))` and you should too.
3. `eval` is totally inappropriate in this code. If you pass `(lambda (x y) (+ x y))` which evaluates to a procedure to OP you can do `(OP 1 2)`. Use `OP` directly.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. All three of those tips worked. My algorithm for 2 didn't work but the CONS solved the syntax. Thank you thank you thank you!